# Python list keep value only if equal to n predecessors

Tags: python

I have a list of signals (representing consecutive mesures) :

```
signals = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I consider a signal valid only if equal to the previous n mesures.

Eg. if we consider only 2 mesures for validation `(n=2)`, the first time signals turns from 0 to 1 we consider it still 0 but the next mesure, if it's 1 again then we consider it is still valid and make it 1. Then we would need 2 mesures of 0 to turn it to 0 again, etc... Here signals are 0 and 1 for simplification but in my application they can be other integers.

Desired output :

```
# For n = 2:
valid_s = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

# For n = 3:
valid_s = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]

# For n = 4:
valid_s = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

I was looking of a pythonesque one-liner way of doing it but can't seem to find the desired output. I tried something along the lines :

```
S = signals

# For n = 2
[S[i] if S[i] == S[i-1] else S[i-2] for i, _ in enumerate(S)]
# gives [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

# For n = 3
[S[i] if S[i] == S[i-1] == S[i-2] else S[i-3] for i, _ in enumerate(S)]
# gives [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Edit : I'm open to `numpy` if it makes it easier as it's already imported.

Comment: Is your desired output for n=2 correct? Do you base your output only on the measured values or on the already "corrected" previous values?

Comment: Yes, for n=2 I need two consecutive 1 or 0 to consider switching to 1 or 0. If I don't have two consecutive, then I keep the previously already validated value. Hence the desired output for n=2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a good way to make this a one-liner / list comprehension. While you could use `all` with a slice of the list to see whether the value is the same as the `n` values before, I don't see a good way to determine which should be the last valid value in case it is not.

Instead, you could use a good-old "many-lines" for loop:

```
signals = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
n = 3

last_valid = 0
current = None
repeated = 0
res = []
for s in signals:
    if s == current:
        repeated += 1
    else:
        repeated = 1
        current = s
    if repeated >= n:
        last_valid = s
    res.append(last_valid)
```

Afterwards, `res` is `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]`

---

Alternatively, a bit shorter, using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby); result is the same:

```
last_valid = 0
res = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(signals):
    m = len(list(g))
    if m >= n:
        res.extend([last_valid] * (n-1) + [k] * (m-n+1))
        last_valid = k
    else:
        res.extend([last_valid] * m)
```

Comment: Addendum: And as always, if you want a one-line solution, just make it a function. ;-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yes, that last one is also nice, but I still prefer my own using list multiplication instead of another nested loop. :-)

Comment: Man, this is one of those problems... I wrote like a dozen different solutions by now... here's one you'll maybe like, it multiplies and it doesn't need `last_valid` (and thus also doesn't have a hard-coded initial value): https://ideone.com/RWkdwq

Comment: @StefanPochmann Interesting, but not sure if this is correct.What if the sequence starts with `1 1 1` and `n = 3`? Should it really produce `1 1 1` in the result, or `0 0 1`? Also, what if it starts `1 1 0`? Yours will produce `1 1 ...` even though it does not occur three times.

Comment: Well, I see nothing in the question that suggests a preference for 0. So I think starting with what the given sequence starts with is *better*, and *not* doing so is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
signal = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

def each(signal, n):
  p = 0
  ring = [ signal[0] ] * (n-1)
  v = None
  for x in signal:
    if v is None or all(q == x for q in ring):
      v = x
    yield v
    ring[p] = x
    p = (p+1) % (n-1)

list(each(signal, 2))
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

But I reconsidered this and think that a pure iterative (less Pythonic) approach is probably more efficient.  After completing my new approach I now think that it is the same idea as @tobias_k already implemented in his answer:

```
def each(signal, n):
  current = signal[0]
  next = None
  for v in signal:
    if v != current:
      if v == next:
        next_count += 1
      else:
        next_count = 1
        next = v
      if next_count >= n:
        current = v
    yield current
```

Comment: Why the `ring`? Why not just a slice of the list?

Comment: Because creating slices is probably more costly than using a ringbuffer.  Depends on implementation which I don't want to rely on.

Comment: Valid point, but the overall complexity is still `O(len(lst)*n)`

Comment: Not sure if this is true.  You only have to do n comparisons it the first n-1 are all true all the time.  This cannot be I think.

Comment: Right, did not think of `all` short circuiting. But still, the more "ordered" the signal is, the worse the running time. Anyway, +1 for a nice, working solution.